# "File name too long error" on embedded Tomcat 8 war maven

Tags: java, linux, maven, tomcat

I was looking for embedded tomcat version 8+ so i had one from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbXb73bU5N4. It was working on my Windows fine and now when I am on Linux and have some issues. I was looking for answers and didn't find anything. If the `class.path.java` is the problem causing that ***file name is too long*** what shall I do?

The error message:

```
Jul 30, 2018 6:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat getWebappConfigFileFromJar
WARNING: Unable to determine web application context.xml /home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jce.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/resources.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/mateuszh/IdeaProjects/embedded/target/classes:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-jasper-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj-4.4.2.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.28/tomcat-catalina-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/8.0.28/tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jsp-api/8.0.28/tomcat-jsp-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-el-api/8.0.28/tomcat-el-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.28/tomcat-juli-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/8.0.28/tomcat-annotations-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/8.0.28/tomcat-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jni/8.0.28/tomcat-jni-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-coyote/8.0.28/tomcat-coyote-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util-scan/8.0.28/tomcat-util-scan-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/8.0.28/tomcat-util-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1/javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:/home/mateuszh/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/182.3684.101/lib/idea_rt.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jce.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/resources.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/mateuszh/IdeaProjects/embedded/target/classes:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-jasper-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj-4.4.2.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.28/tomcat-catalina-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/8.0.28/tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jsp-api/8.0.28/tomcat-jsp-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-el-api/8.0.28/tomcat-el-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.28/tomcat-juli-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/8.0.28/tomcat-annotations-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/8.0.28/tomcat-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jni/8.0.28/tomcat-jni-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-coyote/8.0.28/tomcat-coyote-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util-scan/8.0.28/tomcat-util-scan-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/8.0.28/tomcat-util-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1/javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:/home/mateuszh/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/182.3684.101/lib/idea_rt.jar (File name too long)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.getWebappConfigFileFromJar(Tomcat.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.getWebappConfigFile(Tomcat.java:1117)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:515)
    at com.mateusz.tomcat.embedded.Launcher.startServer(Launcher.java:30)
    at com.mateusz.tomcat.embedded.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:13)

Jul 30, 2018 6:18:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
Jul 30, 2018 6:18:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 30, 2018 6:18:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Jul 30, 2018 6:18:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Jul 30, 2018 6:18:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/embedded]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/embedded]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@51ff5a12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4984)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jce.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/resources.jar:/home/mateuszh/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/mateuszh/IdeaProjects/embedded/target/classes:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-jasper-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj-4.4.2.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.28/tomcat-catalina-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/8.0.28/tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jsp-api/8.0.28/tomcat-jsp-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-el-api/8.0.28/tomcat-el-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.28/tomcat-juli-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/8.0.28/tomcat-annotations-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/8.0.28/tomcat-api-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jni/8.0.28/tomcat-jni-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-coyote/8.0.28/tomcat-coyote-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util-scan/8.0.28/tomcat-util-scan-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/8.0.28/tomcat-util-8.0.28.jar:/home/mateuszh/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1/javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:/home/mateuszh/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/182.3684.101/lib/idea_rt.jar] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more

couldn't start the server
Jul 30, 2018 6:18:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:337)
    at com.mateusz.tomcat.embedded.Launcher.startServer(Launcher.java:33)
    at com.mateusz.tomcat.embedded.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:13)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<artifactId>embedded</artifactId>
<groupId>com.mateusz.tomcat</groupId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.28</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!--create a jar to start the server-->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-launcher-jar</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- unpack jar into the war folder-->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="unzipping file"/>
                            <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
                                   dest="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- make the war file-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>Launcher</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Embedded tomcat  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JavaX -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and my Launcher

```
package com.mateusz.tomcat.embedded;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.Host;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

import java.io.File;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
        try {
            launcher.startServer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("couldn't start the server");
        }
    }

    private void startServer() throws Exception {
        File war = new File(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8888);
        tomcat.setBaseDir(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.out.println("war: " + war);

        Host host = tomcat.getHost();
        host.setAppBase(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        host.setAutoDeploy(true);
        host.setDeployOnStartup(true);
        Context appContext = tomcat.addWebapp(host, "/embedded", war.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Deployed " + appContext.getBaseName() + " as " + appContext.getDocBase());

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have solved the problem by changing one lane. 
`File war = new File(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));`

changed for:
`File war = new File(("."));`
I leave this topic maybe helps someone. If you are against just say and I will delete Topic.

Comment: Add your solution as your own answer, is completely legal in SO, will make the answer more visible and who knows, the source of some reputation points for you. You can accept it after 2 days or so. I removed the "solved" from the title since it's not the regular practice on SO but rather an accepted answer.

Comment: I agree with @LuisMuñoz - post your solution as an answer. The question you asked, and the fix you found, are both worth keeping. And having an accepted answer is much more helpful to the community that a solution buried in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by changing one lane.

```
File war = new File(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

changed for:

```
File war = new File(".");
```